# how to select and count same data used in other colum using sql

Tags: mysql

My database table 'user' have below details

```
 ---------------------------------------
 id |  username  |   ref   |   email
 ---------------------------------------
 1  |  name1     |   0     |    name1@email.com
 2  | name2      |   1     |    name2@email.com
 3  |  name3     |   0     |    name3@email.com
 4  | name4      |   3     |    name4@email.com
 5  | name5      |   3     |    name5@email.com
 6  |  name5     |   0     |    name6@email.com
 ---------------------------------------
```

this means id 3 is the referrer of 4,5 and id 1 is the referrer of id 2 because same id is showing in column ref.
My question is  how to select name of id 4&5 using id 3
And how to count id 3 have how many referrals?
example ans: Name3= 2 ref , Name1= 1 ref

Comment: Please show your expected output and also what you have tried?  Can the referral hierarchy be more than one level deep?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the user whose ref is id 3 by below query :

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE ref = 3
```

Output :

```
id  username    ref email
4   name4       3   name4@email.com
5   name5       3   name5@email.com
```

And you can count the number of user whose ref id is 3 :

```
SELECT count(id) FROM data WHERE ref = 3
```

Output :

```
count(id)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following procedure in mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_tree`(IN `id` NUMBER)
    BEGIN
     DECLARE refid NUMBER;
     DECLARE userid NUMBER;
     SET userid = id;
     SET refid=0;
     SELECT `ref` into refid 
     FROM `user` WHERE `id`=userid;
     create table IF NOT EXISTS temp_table select * from user;
     truncate table temp_table;
     insert into temp_table select * from user;
     WHILE (refid is not 0) DO
       insert into temp_table select * from user WHERE id=userid;
         SET userid = refid;
       SET refid=0;
       SELECT ref into refid
       FROM user WHERE id=userid;
     END WHILE;
     select * from temp_table; 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select u2.username from user u2 where u2.id = u1.ref), count(*) as refs from user u1 where u1.ref > 0 group by u1.ref
```

this is my test code:

```
drop table if exists `user`;

create table if not exists `user`(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name nvarchar(250),
    ref int
);

insert into `user`(id, name, ref) values (1, 'user1', 0);
insert into `user`(id, name, ref) values (2, 'user2', 1);
insert into `user`(id, name, ref) values (3, 'user3', 1);
insert into `user`(id, name, ref) values (4, 'user4', 2);
insert into `user`(id, name, ref) values (5, 'user5', 3);

select (select u2.name from `user` u2 where u2.id = u1.ref), count(*) as refs from `user` u1 where u1.ref > 0 group by u1.ref
```

and the out put is:

|name|refs|

|use1|2|

|use2|1|

|use3|1|